# Como gerar lista de diretórios e executar ações para cada item da lista?

Tags: bash

Estou tentando construir um Shell Script que armazene os diretórios existe na raiz do /Volumes e realize uma iteração sobre estes, ignorando somente o diretório: "Preboot" e "Macintosh H"

Comment: "Interação" ou "iteração"? Se for "interação" poderia explicar que tipo de "interação" deseja?

Comment: `for d in /Volumes/*; do if [ "$d" != "/Volumes/Preboot" -a "$d" != "/Volumes/Macintosh H" ]; then itera "$d"; fi; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Resposta rápida

```
for d in /Volumes/*; do
  if [ "$d" != "/Volumes/Preboot" -a "$d" != "/Volumes/Macintosh H" ]; then
    itera "$d";
  fi;
done
```

## Explicação

`for` vai fazer uma iteração sobre um conjunto de palavras fornecidas. No caso, estamos passando `/Volumes/*`, que será submetido a uma expansão `glob` e, portanto, o argumento de iteração do `for` será todo o conteúdo não oculto de `/Volumes`.

Na condição, estou garantindo que a variável `$d` não seja nem a pasta `Preboot` dentro de `/Volumes` nem `Macintosh H` dentro de `/Volumes` também. Não lembro de nenhuma operação de pertinência no `test`. Poderia ter usado `case/esac` também para ignorar essas opções.

O `test cmd1 -a cmd2`, em específico `-a`, é a operação `and` do comando `test`. Portando, a operação de exemplo do começo deste parágrafo será verdadeira se `cmd1` e `cmd2` forem verdadeiros.

## Disclaimer

Como estou sem computador, fiquei com dúvida quando a expansão `glob` gera opções com espaços no meio, mas creio que mesmo se isso gerar bug no código seja quase trivial corrigi-lo.

Comment: Obrigado pelo auxilio, resultado final:
#!/bin/bash
for d in /Volumes/*; do
  if [ "$d" != "/Volumes/Preboot" -a "$d" != "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" ]; then
    cd "$d" && find . -type f \( -iname "._*" -o -name ".DS_Store" \) -exec rm "{}" \;
    echo "Removendo arquivos \"._*\" e \".DS_Store\" de: $d";
  fi;
done

e ai chamo com um alias.